# SAP R/3 BAPI - PHP

Tags: open-source, php

I am looking for a rock-solid, still-maintained open-source solution to communicate with SAP R/3 BAPI from within PHP. I am interested in your personal opinions from your own experiences.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially you should explicitely mention your exact requirements: what features do you need? Must it be free, or do you have a budget?